# A fictional fish's favorite

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

It is..

> Something kids in a bath might do,
>   A dash of flavor to add to your food.
>   A scattering of shade,
>   An impression well made,
>   The first of many screens that is viewed.

What does a fictional fish love to do?

You don't have to figure out the fish, but bonus smiley face if you do.

Comment: Oh wow, a limerick. Can't remember the last time I saw one of those!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> Splash, with varying definitions

Something kids in a bath might do,

> def: strike or move around in a body of water, causing it to fly about noisily.

A dash of flavor to add to your food.

> def: a small quantity of liquid added.

A scattering of shade,

> def: be decorated with scattered patches of.

And impression well made,

> def: a striking, ostentatious, or exciting effect or event.

The first of many screens that is viewed.

> Splash page of a website

What does a fictional fish love to do?

> Magikarp? Only move is Splash

Comment: That'd be it! and  a scattering of shade was also alluding to splashes of color, like for art work. Bonus smile awarded :)